# LibGDX: black rectangles instead of animation textures

Tags: java, android, graphics, libgdx

I use AssetManager to manage assets in my libgdx game. I have static images and animations. When I used emulator (Nexus 6, Api 29) to test the game it was fine, but once I emulated the game to my real phone (Samsung J5 2016, Api 25) it started showing black rectangles instead of some animations, but static textures were fine.

My animations are 800x800 px, 10 fps.

Here is an example of such texture. This code is in Loading screen:

```
assetManager.load(AssetDescriptors.BONUS_TEXTURE);
```

Here I instantiate animation, frame time = 0.1f. This code is in factory, that creates the object with such animation:

```
animationComponent.animation = new Animation<>(GameData.FRAME_TIME,
                assetManager.get(AssetDescriptors.BONUS_TEXTURE).getRegions());
```

And here I draw it. This is from the class that manages rendering:

```
batch.draw(animationComponent.animation.getKeyFrame(animationComponent.elapsedTime, true),
                position.x - dimension.width / 2f, position.y - dimension.height / 2f,
                dimension.width, dimension.height
        );
```

This works on emulator and doesn`t work on real device. Please tell me what can be wrong. Thank you for your help.

[emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1hUo.png) [emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Bfy.png)

[phone - player, pot and gran animations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo59u.jpg) [phone - gran and pot animations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WTzx.jpg)

Comment: Add pictures so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many devices don't support textures with dimensions that are not a power of two. You should pack your textures with TexturePacker and keep the `pot` setting on.